# Squid not forwarding my packets proxied from iptables on router

Tags: iptables, routing, proxy, squid, http-proxy

I am trying to make openwrt's iptables from my router to direct to my squid proxy on my machine (since there is no enough space in router's flash memory) but even if I have my squid config ok ( meaning I set it up as proxy in my system and it works fine) when I set this up I won't get any response

```
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -s 192.168.1.0/255.255.255.0 -p tcp -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.196:3128
```

What should I change in my config ?

I have something like this

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -s ! squid-box -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to squid-box:3128
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -s local-network -d squid-box -j SNAT --to iptables-box
```

but I do not really understand how should I perform this with my config.

```
br-lan    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX 
          inet addr:192.168.1.1  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
          inet addr:188.XXX.XX.XX  Bcast:188.246.39.255  Mask:255.255.252.0
```

Answer (score 1):

I also have an openwrt router configured to forward anything going to port 80 to port 3128 and then SNATting it to include the router's ip fro every client request. 
The thing is that everything was working with the default config ( transparent only added) with the 3.2 version but the 3.3.8 version is not happy. If I switch it to transparent and use the above rules in openwrt, it is denying everything. If I switch it to manual ( configure each client separately) it is working as expected..